# Фильтр вывода из БД при onClick

Tags: php, javascript

Есть несколько ссылок и главный контент где выводится одна таблица из БД.
При нажатии на одну из ссылок надо отфильтровать вывод из БД и обновить только главный контент.
Все найденные примеры не подходят.
Подкиньте пожалуйста хорошую идею.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться AJAX-загрузкой, например, при помощи библиотеки jQuery. Создайте файл user.php, в котором выводите информацию из базы данных по фильтру $_GET['filter']. Для каждого из фильтров следует сформировать WHERE-условие и набор параметров для их выполнения

```
<?php
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    'root',
    '',
    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

  $where = [];
  $conditions = [];
  $where[] = "1 = 1";
  if(isset($_GET['filter'])) {
    switch ($_GET['filter']) {
      case 'show':
          $where[] = "is_active = :is_active";
          $conditions[] = ['is_active' => $_GET['filter']];
          break;
      case 'even':
          $where[] = "is_even = :is_even";
          $conditions[] = ['is_even' => $_GET['filter']];
          break;
    }
  }

  $query = "SELECT * 
            FROM users
            WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $where);
  $usr = $pdo->prepare($query);
  $usr->execute($conditions);
  while($user = $usr->fetch()) {
    echo "<div>".htmlspecialchars($user['name'])."</div>";
  }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Невозможно установить соединение с базой данных";
}
```

Тогда основной файл index.php может вообще не содержать PHP-кода, а загружать его только средствами JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
  <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Назначить обработчики события click
    // после загрузки документа
    $(function(){
      $("a.filter").on("click", function(){
        // Формируем ссылку для AJAX-обращения
        var url = "user.php?filter=" + $(this).attr('id');
        // Отправляем AJAX-запрос и выводим результат
        $.ajax({
          url: encodeURI(url)
        }).done(function(data){
          $('#info').html(data).removeClass("hidden");
        });
      });
      // Кликаем на ссылку #all сами, чтобы отобразить 
      // первичный вывод при первой загрузке
      $('#all').trigger('click')
    });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a class='filter' id='all' href='#'>all</a>
      <a class='filter' id='show' href='#'>show</a>
    </div>
    <div id='info' class='hidden'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Здесь мы перезагружаем область . При этом мы можем добавлять любое количество ссылок-фильтров с классом .filter, им будет назначен AJAX-обработчик, перезагружающий область с классом .info.

Comment: "В реальном примере, вам потребуется сформировать WHERE-условие SQL-запроса с учетом содержимого GET-параметра filter." - как мне это зделать?
и что должен содержать "jquery.js" ?

Comment: Сложность именно с этой частью?

Comment: Да. У меня будет около 40 картинок - сылок по которым нада будет нажать о фильтровать

Comment: Поправил, но вам придется адаптировать пример под собственную таблицу